# To remove blank lines in data set

Tags: perl, shell, sed, awk

I need a one liner using sed, awk or perl to remove blank lines from my data file. The data in my file looks like this -

```
Aamir
Ravi 

Arun


Rampaul
Pankaj

Amit

Bianca
```

These blanks are at **random** and **appear anywhere** in my data file. Can someone suggest a one-liner to remove these blank lines from my dataset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it can be done in many ways.

e.g with awk:

```
awk '$0' yourFile
```

or sed:

```
sed '/^$/d' yourFile
```

or grep:

```
grep -v '^$' yourFile
```

Answer (score 6):

A Perl solution. From the command line.

```
$ perl -i.bak -n -e'print if /\S/' INPUT_FILE
```

Edits the file in-place and creates a backup of the original file.

Answer (score 3):

**AWK Solution:**

Here we loop through the input file to check if they have any field set. NF is AWK's in-built variable that is set to th number of fields. If the line is empty then NF is not set. In this one liner we test if NF is true, i.e set to a value. If it is then we print the line, which is implicit in AWK when the pattern is true.

```
awk 'NF' INPUT_FILE
```

**SED Solution:**

This solution is similar to the ones mentioned as the answer. As the syntax show we are not printing any lines that are blank.

```
sed -n '/^$/!p' INPUT_FILE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
 sed -i.bak '/^$/d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution:

```
perl -ni.old -e 'print unless /^\s*$/' file
```

...which create as backup copy of the original file, suffixed with '.old'

Answer (score 1):

for perl it is as easier as sed,awk, or grep.

```
$ cat tmp/tmpfile
Aamir
Ravi

Arun


Rampaul
Pankaj

Amit

Bianca

$ perl -i -pe 's{^\s*\n$}{}' tmp/tmpfile

$ cat tmp/tmpfile
Aamir
Ravi
Arun
Rampaul
Pankaj
Amit
Bianca
```

Comment: here the names are displayed with space delimiter. but in shell the names are displayed one below the other without any blank lines.