# Delete blank rows in a csv file in Python

Tags: python, file, csv

I have some csv files in a folder and I am trying to delete all blank rows and move the news files into a new folder.

Here is the code I have:

```
import csv
import glob
import os
import shutil

path = 'in_folder/*.csv'
files=glob.glob(path)

#Read every file in the directory

x = 0 #counter

for filename in files:

    with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
        data = fin.read().splitlines(True)

        with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
            for line in fin.readlines():
                if ''.join(line.split(',')).strip() == '':
                    continue
                fout.write(line)
            x += 1            


dir_src = "in_folder"
dir_dst = "out_folder"


for file in os.listdir(dir_src):
    if x>0:
        src_file = os.path.join(dir_src, file)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dir_dst, file)
        shutil.move(src_file, dst_file)
```

What the code is doing right now is deleting everything from the files and moving them to the new folder. I want my files to be the same but with deleted blank rows.

Comment: So do you want to modify the original? Delete the original?

Comment: Or in Perl (example is for single file) !! - 
    perl -ni.old -e 'print unless /^\s*$/' file 
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270397/1755628)

Comment: @PeterWood Delete the empty rows, and put the new file into a new folder.

Comment: You're not being precise. Do you want the original file gone? If not, do you want the original file modified?

Comment: I want the original file modified.

Answer (score 1):

You can just output every line to the new file, no need to do any moving afterwards:

```
dir_src = "in_folder/*.csv"
dir_dst = "out_folder"

files = glob.glob(dir_src)

# Read every file in the directory

x = 0 # counter

for filename in files:
    outfilename = os.path.join(dir_dst, os.path.basename(filename))
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
        with open(outfilename, 'w') as fout:
            for line in fin:
                if ''.join(line.split(',')).strip() == '':
                    continue
                fout.write(line)
            x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
        data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
        with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
            for line in data:
                if ''.join(line.split(',')).strip() == '':
                    continue
                fout.write(line)
            x += 1
```